# Rails 5: allow javascript posted image from controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am posting an image (or multiple images) to my controller via Javascript. I am using Carrierwave + Rails 5 for image uploads.

The image comes across in the params like this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"file"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fcc92da6c70 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/3m/9jgntpps1j5gzkm444tq6t400000gn/T/RackMultipart20180208-2884-15wx288.jpeg>, @original_filename="1.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[0]\"; filename=\"1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"listings", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

I am trying to allow that into my controller somehow. This seems to fail:

```
@listing.pictures = params[:file]
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Picture(#70258317227420) expected, got "0" which is an instance of String(#70258262105620)
```

This also seems to fail:

```
@listing.pictures = params[:file]['0']
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fcc92da6c70>
```

I'm not sure how to add the pictures to my model from this POST request. Any ideas?

The relation between Listing and Picture looks like this:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
@listing.pictures = params[:file].values.map {|file| Picture.new(image: file)}
```

Comment: Gives the following error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Picture(#70188093733320) expected, got #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fabe6f14070 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/3m/9jgntpps1j5gzkm444tq6t400000gn/T/RackMultipart20180208-4872-cyar8c.jpeg>, @original_filename="1.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[0]\"; filename=\"1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"> which is an instance of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile(#70188091823640)`

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked. Is this less safe than making it go through Rails' strong params?

Comment: short answer: in this case, there is no risk. Long answer strong params are ridiculous: https://medium.com/@apneadiving/why-i-do-not-use-strong-parameters-in-rails-e3bd07fcda1d